# how to select rows and count values from a binary data set in perl?

Tags: perl, selection, grouping, sum

I hope any of you can help me. I have a data set similar to this:

```
0100010011  
1011100100  
0001001100  


0101111011  
0010000100  
1101111011  


0000111000  
0001000101  
1110000010  


0001000011  
0110111100  
1001000001
```

This example consist in only four 'paragraphs' with three rows each one, with 10 digits per row. My real data is a lot larger, it has 1000 paragraphs with 100 rows each one, with 50 digits per row (all binary data).
I need to calculate the number of times that "1" is present per column per paragraph. I have been searching on the web and found this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @LineTotalsArray;

while (my $line = <stdin>) {
   print $line;
   chomp $line;

   my $index=0;
   for my $val ( split /\t/, $line ) {
      $LineTotalsArray[ $index++ ] += $val;
   }
}

print join('=', @LineTotalsArray), "\n";
```

This works fine for "ALL" the file, it does not differentiate between paragraphs, so it gives me the TOTAL account of "1" per column in the whole data set:4 5 4 7 5 5 5 5 5 6

```
0100010011  
1011100100  
0001001100  


0101111011  
0010000100  
1101111011  


0000111000  
0001000101  
1110000010  


0001000011  
0110111100  
1001000001  

4547555556
```

Does any of you have any idea of what can I do in this case? how can i tell in perl, that I want to do "this" operation every, let's say, "three rows"?.

Thanks for your help, any suggestion will be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If the input data set is not already in chunks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @counts;
my $every_n = 3;

while (my $row =  <DATA>) {
    last unless my @digits = $row =~ /([01])/g;
    $counts[($. - 1) / $every_n][$_] += $digits[$_] for 0 .. $#digits;
}

print Dump \@counts;

__DATA__
0100010011
1011100100
0001001100
0101111011
0010000100
1101111011
0000111000
0001000101
1110000010
0001000011
0110111100
1001000001
```

If the input data set is already in chunks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @counts;

{
    local $/ = "";
    while ( my $chunk = <DATA> ) {
        while ( $chunk =~ /([01]+)/g ) {
            my @digits = $1 =~ /([01])/g;
            $counts[$. - 1][$_] += $digits[$_] for 0 .. $#digits;
        }
    }
}

print Dump \@counts;

__DATA__
0100010011
1011100100
0001001100

0101111011
0010000100
1101111011

0000111000
0001000101
1110000010

0001000011
0110111100
1001000001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @LineTotalsArray;

while (my $line = <stdin>) {
    print $line;
    chomp $line;

    my $index=0;

    chomp;
    my @val = (split /\t/, $line);

    if (@val <= 1) {
            print "=", join('=', @LineTotalsArray), "\n";
            @LineTotalsArray = undef;
    }

    else {
            for my $val ( split /\t/, $line ) {
                    $LineTotalsArray[ $index++ ] += $val;
            }
    }
}

print "=", join('=', @LineTotalsArray), "\n";
```

Finish with a blank line. You need to print your results and clean your array on each blank line. There are a lot of ways to check for a blank line (0 length after chomp, regexp '^$', etc... I would probably do zero length, but this was just a quick change to your code).

Comment: Thanks! It works. I just have to fix it a little bit for the last 'paragraph'

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my %totals;

{
$/ = "\n\n";

while (my $chunk = <DATA>) {
   chomp $chunk;
   my @line_totals;

   for my $line (split /\n/, $chunk) {
      my $index = 0;
      for (split //, $line ) {
          $line_totals[$index++] += $_;
      }
   }
   say $chunk;
   say @line_totals, "\n";
   $totals{$chunk} = join '', @line_totals;
}
}

say Dumper \%totals;
```

This only works if the data is already separated in chunks, like in your example. We set the [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to a double newline; After that, it's a matter of splitting the chunks into lines, and the lines into parts we sum together.

If I may, a subquestion of my own: Can anyone think of a solution that uses vec instead?

EDIT: I kept wondering if I could do the inner part with a regex. Here's my feeble attempt:

```
{
$/ = "\n\n";

while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   our @lines_total = ();
   my $index = 0;
   () = /(?
           (?<=^)
             ([0-1])(?{ $index = 0; $lines_total[$index] += $^N })
           |
             ([0-1])(?{ $lines_total[++$index] += $^N })
          )/xmg;
   say join '', @lines_total;

}
}
```

(Had to use our because of a bug. It's explained in perlre)